# What does reduced saturation pressure mean in acentric factor?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, phase-diagram

I'm currently learning about acentric factor and I don't understand what P_r^sat means... Is there a saturation pressure at critical point? Moreover, is the reason for setting reduced temperature as 0.7 when calculating acentric factor just for convenience?